# What is the minimum supported MacOS Version the Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to develop Window and MacOS programs using Xamarin Forms. However, I am curious what is the minimum supported version of Xamarin for MacOS.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/supported-platforms?tabs=macos) says that it is MacOS 10.13 or higher but, when creating a project through Visual Studio, you can set the minimum supported version up to 10.7.

The storyboard is from 10.10. What is really the minimum supported version?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

> The documentation says that it is MacOS 10.13 or higher

If you want to develop a MacOS application and need to runing in macOS Mojave, you will need the MacOS 10.13 or higher. Because the macOS Mojave (10.14) SDK ships with Xcode 10 and is required to build apps that use the newest macOS APIs. And Xcode 10 requires macOS High Sierra (10.13) or newer.

> but when creating a project through Visual Studio, you can set the minimum supported version up to 10.7.

If you need to develop older macOS versions application, you need to use old version of Xamarin.Mac.Here is the warning from the [macOS requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements#macos-requirements):

> Xamarin.Mac 4.8 only supports macOS 10.9 (Mavericks) or higher.
> Previous versions of Xamarin.Mac supported macOS 10.7 or higher, but
> these older macOS versions lack sufficient TLS infrastructure to
> support TLS 1.2. To target macOS 10.7 or macOS 10.8, use Xamarin.Mac
> 4.6 or earlier.

And you can refer to [Xamarin.Mac release notes and API changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/release-notes/) to know which version of Xamarin Mac mathch which version of MacOS.

**In short**, you could develop old version of MacOS application, but you also need to use the matched version of Xamarin.Mac. If Visual Studio not supports the version of Xamarin.Mac, you will not develop that version of MacOS appliation.